# Proper date formatting using Get-Date cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to generate timestamp with the following format
`2017-11-11T19:33:27`.

With `Get-Date -Format o` I am able generate `2017-11-13T07:39:32.7958466-05:00`

How can I remove milliseconds `.7958466-05:00` in the generated output?

Comment: I edited your title and text as you talked about `Get-Content` instead of `Get-Date`

Answer (score 3):

Use `Get-Date -Format s` instead of `Get-Date -Format o`

[Formatting Dates and Times](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)